# GWT script tag placement

Tags: gwt

Is there a difference (performance or other) between putting the GWT application's script tag in the head and in the body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have just a simple html page that just loads the GWT app and maybe a spinning "Loading" gif, then it makes no difference. The html-code generate the page almost instantly. GWT method `RootPanel.get("id")` also work very quickly. Almost all time of page generation will be the loading of gwt-module. So place your gwt-application where it is more convenient to you.

If you have a regular html page you may want the script at the bottom so all the other content - images etc - will load first and be visible to the user, before loading the script.